# Can I use laravel5 packages in Lumen?

Tags: php, pdf, laravel-5, lumen

I was developing REST API's in Laravel5 and now I am moving same project to Lumen due to speed issue.
The problem is,I am using `"vsmoraes/laravel-pdf": "1.0.1"` in Laravel,Now I want to use the same in Lumen.
How it is possible?

When I am added via composer and trying to access from controller,I am getting following error ,

```
    BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 785:
    Target [Vsmoraes\Pdf\Pdf] is not instantiable.
```

Any idea?

Comment: So, what were you expecting, exactly? If the package has specific Laravel dependencies, it most likely won't work on Lumen. Just because Lumen uses a subset of Laravel's packages, it doesn't mean is a 1:1 replacement. Laravel also uses a lot of Symfony components and you wouldn't add a Symfony specific package and expect to work out of the box, would you?

Answer (score 1):

Lumen is a micro-framework based on Laravel. As of that, Lumen does not have all the Laravel featuers (by default).

Most of the packages will have to be updated, so they will have much less Laravel-specific dependencies than they're having now.